# WP full site migration (to another host with different domain) 403 error

Tags: database-migration, http-status-code-403, contact-form-7, data-migration

I received a request to completely move a wordpress site from one host to another and change the domain name to it as well. I downloaded the database and the files and folders, uploaded to the other host. Everything works well except for 2 forms(Contact form 7 plugins). Every time I try changing the settings to the contact form, when I hit "Save" it triggers a 403 error .

I regenerated the .htaccess from root public folder(there are many more such files deeper, some made by different plugins), I checked the files and folders permissions...couldn't get around that 403 error. I made the changes the client wanted for the contact form 7 plugin directly into the corresponding database table and it works.

How should I tackle into this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A security plugin was triggering it. Problem solved